# Detect first character in textfield with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'd like to know how to do the following with Jquery:

I have 1 textfield in a form. 
Whenever the first character is a number, change the attr name of this field to 'number'. If the first character is a letter, change this attr name to 'letter'.

!! This also has to work when a number or text is copy-pasted into the field.

Thanks!
Jeroen

Comment: Does this have to happen as you type (more complicated), or when the onchange attribute fires (easy)?

Comment: That reads more like a freelancer spec than a question for SO.

Comment: Does copy-pasting also count as typing?

Comment: @Jroen - You tell us, it's your question and your requirement. (Is this homework?) But you can paste with the keyboard or the mouse, so in my opinion it's not typing but is "editing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind (some) event(s) to the text field: The **`keyup`** event is used to update the `name` attribute when the user modifies the text (including shortcut `CTRL+V` copy-pasting),
 the **`paste`** and **`mousemove`** events are used to deal with copy-pasting (dragging, contextmenu).

```
$("#your-input").bind("keyup paste mousemove", function() {
    var char = this.value.charAt(0);     // Use vanilla JavaScript to get the
                                         // first character of the text field
    if (/[0-9]/.test(char)) {            // Test against a pattern: digit
        $(this).attr("name ", "number");
    } else if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(char)) {  // Else, pattern: letters
        $(this).attr("name", "letter");
    } else {                             // Finally, no name?
        $(this).attr("name", "");
    }
});
```

Remove `else {...}`, and replace `else if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(char)) {` *with* `else {` if you want the default name to be `letter`.

Comment: The `change` event will not handle the right-click when it happens.. just on `blur`.. Better to use the `paste` event which will handle the paste the moment it happens. This will be consistent with the `keyup`..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Good point, I've changed `change` to `paste`.

Comment: I've found the paste event to be pretty unreliable as far as cross-browser support (sorry, I forget off-hand which browser(s) had a problem with it). Also it doesn't cover drag'n'drop changes to the field.

Comment: P.S. You'd also need to handle the cut event, and some browsers have "Delete" on their "Edit" menu - which if accessed via mouse wouldn't trigger mouse events on the field.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$("#yourformid").submit(function(){
   var input = $("#yourinputid"),
       val = input.val();
   input.attr("name", /^\d/.test(val) ? "number" :
                      /^[A-Z]/i.test(val) ? "letter" : "");
});
```

It's difficult to handle paste in all browsers, but if you just set the attribute when the form is submitted you're covered no matter what the user does including drag'n'drop changes to the field. (Obviously I'm assuming it doesn't matter what the attribute is before submit.)